# how to run tests in parallel with the singleton driver?

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit-3.0

The driver is singleton and I want to run the tests in parallel,

***NOTE: Without using singleton if it works well***

example:

Singleton Class

```
public static class Driver
{
    public static IWebDriver GetInstance()
    {
        if (driver == null)
        {
                driver = new ChromeDriver(//PATH);              
        }
        return driver;
    }
    public static void SetNull()
    {
        driver = null;
    }
}
```

**TestCase (father class)**

```
[TestFixture, Apartment(ApartmentState.MTA)]
[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Self)]
public class TestCase
{
    private IWebDriver driver;

    [SetUp]
    public void Initilize()
    {
        driver = Driver.GetInstance();
        Driver.GetInstance().Navigate().GoToUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url"]);
        Driver.GetInstance().Manage().Window.Maximize();    
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void EndTest()
    {
        if (Driver.GetInstance() != null)
        {
            try
            {
                //Pending Logout
            }
            finally
            {
                Driver.GetInstance().Close();
                Driver.GetInstance().Quit();
                Driver.SetNull();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**TESTCASE 1, 2, 3... N**

```
[TestFixture, Apartment(ApartmentState.MTA)]
class TC85874_Login : TestCase
{
    [Test, Apartment(ApartmentState.MTA)]
    public void TC_85874_Login(string user, string password)
    {
        try
        {


            //CODE


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {



        }
    }
}
```

parallel: **[assembly: LevelOfParallelism(3)]**

Assembly **[assembly:Apartment(ApartmentState.MTA)]**

i try with **[Test, RequiresThread(ApartmentState.STA)]** and **RequiresThread Attribute**
*and not working correctly with parallel execution with the singleton driver*

***NOTE: Without using singleton if it works well***

C#, Nunit 3

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: how to run the tests in parallel with the singleton driver?, thanks

Comment: A single IWebDriver instance indicates a single browser that it has launched and manages it. If you want to execute test on multiple instance of chrome in parallel, you will need as many instance of IWebdriver as well...With singleton that won't be possible since you will always get the same instance of IWebdriver .

Comment: A Singleton is the representation of a unique and single instance, and a single driver instance is a single browser, you cant run 2 flows in the same browser...., thats why it works without been a singleton.